# Will there be race conditions or how does this work with multiple calls been made to same method of the same object

Tags: java, multithreading, asynchronous, thread-safety

I have a Singleton : ABCSingleton. This has @Asynchronous methods on it.

Another Object : DecoratorForSingleton decorates the ABCSingleton. Delegates calls to Singleton.

2 separate objects, PQRService and XYZService, need access to ABCSingleton through the decorator.

I created 2 separate instances of DecoratorForSingleton for each - PQRService and XYZService. That was to avoid race conditions or to avoid issues coming out of multiple calls been made to the same instance.

Should I be creating only one instance of DecoratorForSingleton for the 2 objects, PQRService and XYZService ??

None of the classes extend Thread or implement Runnable.

Which one is the better approach ?

Thanks

Comment: hard to tell without seeing the code.

Answer (score 1):

From what I read you have something like

```
class Singleton {
  static final Singleton INSTANCE = new Single();
}

public class Decorator { 
  public void foo(){ 
     Singleton.INSTANCE.foo()
  }
}
public class PQRService {
   Decorator decorator = new Decorator();
}
public class XYZSerivce {
   Decorator decorator = new Decorator();
}
```

If this is the case, you gain nothing from creating individual `Decorator` instances.  Though they are local to the service instance, they share a potentially mutable `Singleton.INSTANCE`.  You will still need to synchronize access to your Singleton.